# Создание массива заданной длины

Tags: golang, массивы

Этот кусок кода выведет массив 4х4 заполненный нулями

```
var tmp [4][4]float64
fmt.Println(tmp)
```

Как создать этот же массив, где размерность задается не явно, а через переменную

```
n := 5
var tmp [n][n]float64
fmt.Println(tmp)
```

Пробовал через `make([][]float64, n)`, не пойму как он работает, вроде создает массив, но пустой(не инициализорованный), о как бы есть и как бы нет

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Если вы не знаете заранее размерность вашего массива, вам прекрасно подойдет и пустой

```
var tmp [][]float64
```

Ну а заполнить его нулями (или чем нить более полезным) легко можно, с помощью **append**, что-то типа такого:

```
var n   = 4
var tmp [][]float64

for i:=0; i<n; i++ {
    tmp = append(tmp, []float64{})
    for j:=0; j<n; j++ {
        tmp[i] = append(tmp[i], 0)  
    }
}

fmt.Println(tmp)
```

Comment: Пустой массив будет пустым всегда. Не путайте массивы и срезы. Массив всегда задается определенного размера, и его размер нельзя изменить.

Comment: @JonnyManowar Спасибо! Действительно, без этого уточнения, мой ответ явно был не полон. Хотя, не думаю, что по прошествии четырёх лет, ТС так об этом и не узнал)))

Comment: Смысл существования этого сайта не только в том чтобы один человек получил ответ на свой вопрос но и в том что бы другие люди, с таким же или похожим вопросом мог найти ответ, а не создавать сотни одинаковых вопросов